# HSQLDB triggers OutOfMemoryError when using nested queries and the DB is in read-only mode

Tags: hsqldb

For a complex use case with about 300000 queries we are using HSQLDB in read-only mode. After a short time, we run into an `OutOfMemoryError`.

The problem is the combination of sub-select queries and read only, all other combinations work fine and fast:

```
               simple select   nested select
DB read only   works           OOM
DB read/write  works           works
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oroicjk44bpvp2g/OOM-read-only-repro.zip) is a simple reproducer including a (read only) data base for the reproducer.

To switch to a read/write DB, simple delete the line "readonly=true" in repo.properties and run the test again.

I suspect that the `RowStoreAVLHybrid`class is part of the problem, because that class only is used in the subselect+read-only case.

Any idea what i can do besides switching the database to read/write, what i want to avoid at all cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no workaround for this bug. It has been resovled and a fix committed to the dev-three code branch for the HSQLDB version 2.5.0 release.